# Calculating heat loss

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am given that the specific heat capacity of tin is $0.394k~\mathrm{J\,kg^{-1} K^1}$

I am to work out how much heat is lost by a block of tin with mass $100~\mathrm{kg}$ when it cools from $100$ to $50^\circ~\mathrm{C}.$

I'm given mass and initial/final temperature, I just don't know where to go in terms of which equation to use. Please could somebody point me in the right direction? Many thanks!

Comment: So with it asking how much heat is lost, it is asking me how much energy is lost. Therefore I need an equation that finds DeltaQ.

Comment: Just doing some workings out, am I right in saying the equation I am after is 

Q=m x temp change x c (specific heat)

So:

100 x 50 x 0.394

Comment: Am I required to transfer celcius into kelvins by the way? Many thanks! The difference would still be 50 as with temperature.

Comment: The difference of 1 K is exactly of one Celsius degree. So as long as you avoid using Fahrenheit, you get along without temperature conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just  multiply "394 J/kg/K" with the temperature difference of "50 K" and the mass "100 kg". What number do you get? What units will remain and which will annihilate with each other?

Comment: 1,970,000 J is my answer once kJ has been converted. Isn't that a bit outrageous for an answer?

Comment: OK, you are right now. My answer is outrageously short, that's right. The number is not outrageous, it is just a half of kilowatt-hour. 10 cents for electricity. Should it be more or less?

Comment: Same answer again.

I think I am required to answer with my first method. 

0.394 x 50 x 100

= 1970 J

Comment: Because the value for C is 0.394

Comment: The original confusion came from that you were given the thermal capacity in different units, "kJ" instead of "J".

Comment: You are welcome. Surely it was easier and much cheaper than buying 100 kg of tin to measure it.